# Python - Convert Visual Studio Project to Docker Image with all dependencies

Tags: python, visual-studio, docker

I have just started to coding Python. And developing a Hello World application with using Flask.

Scenario is basically like that;

1. Write program in Python which will act as http server (you can use Flask or any other modules)

1.1  Server should accept GET requests for any path (http://localhost/*)

1.2  Server should return html page which will contain value of URI path

Example: http://localhost/hello_world should return html page with hello_world

1.3 Put this program to GitHub with README.md describing how-to setup environment and start program

2. Convert this application to Docker image with all dependencies
3. Upload this image to Docker Hub and provide its name

I think, I have completed first item. Also you can see the basic application here.

**My question is, can I convert a Visual Studio Python Project to Docket Image. And does my project provide the requirements? I will be so glad if you can comment for it.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio has a feature that will do it all for you. It's going to be multiple steps.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. With a quick Google search you could find several solutions.

From the Python DockerHub page:

```
FROM python:3.6
# Copy and install requirements for the app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# Execute the program
CMD ["python", "your-main-file-here.py"]
```

After that you need an account to DockerHub and you can push your generated image there.

As for the requirements, if you are using a virtual environment, you can simply do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and that should generate the requirements for you. Otherwise you're gonna have to generate the contents yourself. Unless Visual Studio can somehow(i'm not aware) track the used libraries.